# Create a PHP Random Paragraph Generator

Tags: php, html, css

I am looking at creating a random paragraph generator created from separate sentences that are all grouped together within their own values or structure of the paragraph.

i.e. We will have 3 versions of the opening sentence, 3 versions of the second sentence and 3 versions of the final sentence, so our final product will be showing 3 sentences making our paragraph and picking one at random from each of the 3 groups.

How would I make a PHP script that would generate the three sentences and just put them one after each other?

I have looked online and found multiple random number generators, but none that actually put each number in order and do it all at once. Any ideas or direction would be great, I am NOT asking for code.

EDIT: It's all single array and just will be written in raw, no need to pull from database, so reasonably simple.

Comment: what is the structure of the data, is it all in a single array, a MD array, are you looking to pull it from the database and haven't done that yet... we need more information to be able to help you

Comment: Hi @Kender I have updated my question above.

Comment: Well, you have 27 possible paragraphs... I would generate 3 random numbers and then use each number to pick one of the sentences from each of the 3 groups (opening, second, final).  How well the random numbers are generated is not critical in this application.

Comment: I would suggest a md array... `$paragraphs = array('1' => array('option one', 'option two', 'option three'), '2' => array('option one', 'option two', 'option three'), '3' => array('option one', 'option two', 'option three'));` and then using [php's array_rand() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), or the [rand() function](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is too broad. But this can get you a feel on how it might look.

```
    $sentences = array(
        array('sen1-1', 'sen1-2', 'sen1-3'), 
        array('sen2-1', 'sen2-2', 'sen2-3'), 
        array('sen3-1', 'sen3-2', 'sen3-3')
    );
    echo $sentences[0][rand(0, 2)] . $sentences[1][rand(0, 2)] .$sentences[2][rand(0, 2)];
```

Comment: I like this! Simlple and it was something like this that I actually had in mind, my apologies on my question being broad, I wasn't intending, I tried multiple forums and other methods first. 

I'm now going to be looking into making this a button activated echo.. I really appreciate your help noam.

Comment: Happy to help Owen. I would add that doing high quality language generation will include building a much more interesting model (similar to a an Automata) that might also learn which sentences might be used from an input learning set.

Comment: It's very clever, and quite simple PHP, it's just the basic arrays that enables it to cretae a sentence, but I'm very happy with the above. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this:

```
$sentences = array(
    array('A - first', 'A - second', 'A - third'),
    array('B - first', 'B - second', 'B - third'),
    array('C - first', 'C - second', 'C - third')
);

$selected = array();
foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
    $selected[] = $sentence[rand(0, count($sentence) - 1)];
}

$paragraph = implode(' ', $selected);
echo $paragraph;

// => A - second B - first C - second
```